# Uri must be non null or empty taking a photo

Tags: android, camera

Im trying to take a photo when i press my circleimageview, after take the photo crop it and then begin uploading to firebase, the thing is that i press and the camera opens correctly but when i take the photo the app crashes sending me this error `Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537, result=-1, data=Intent  Uri must be non null or empty`

i start here by setting the imageview an `onClickListener` to launch the camera, and below in `ActivityResults` method i just check the permisions and save the pick

```
private Uri  mImageUri = null;

  mProfileImageView = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.profileImageView);
        mProfileImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), "android.permission.CAMERA") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    cameraIntent();

                } else {
                    requestPerms();
                }


            }
        });

        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            mImageUri = data.getData();

            CropImage.activity(mImageUri)
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(getContext(), this);

        }

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                mImageUri = result.getUri();
                mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                StorageReference filePath = mStorageUsers.child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

                mProgress.setMessage("Estableciendo foto de perfil ...");
                mProgress.show();

                filePath.putFile(mImageUri)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                                mDatabaseUsers.child("profile_picture").setValue(downloadUri.toString());

                                mProfileImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);

                                mProgress.dismiss();
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                mProgress.dismiss();

                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), e.getClass().getSimpleName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });

            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {

                Exception error = result.getError();
            }

        }

    }
```

Camera trigger

```
private void cameraIntent(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

Any idea why this problem ? 
here is my logcat

```
06-14 16:32:05.126 4783-4783/com.app.myyapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.app.myyapp, PID: 4783
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.app.myyapp/com.app.myyapp.FragmentMain}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Uri must be non null or empty
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4094)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4137)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1529)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Uri must be non null or empty
                                                                      at com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage.activity(CropImage.java:358)
                                                                      at com.pholy.pholyapp.presentation.feed_user_images.view.PerfilFragment.onActivityResult(PerfilFragment.java:250)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:164)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6931)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4090)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4137) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1529) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not show the code used to trigger the `CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE` scenario in `onActivityResult()`.

Assuming that it is `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, that does not give you a `Uri` via `data.getData()`. Instead:

- If you put `EXTRA_OUTPUT` on your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`, the image should be in the location that you specified there
- Otherwise, you get a `Bitmap` back from `data.getParcelableExtra("data")`

Comment: i trigger the camera here 

private void cameraIntent(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

Comment: i updated my question, if i can solve this problem i should solve another ones that im having with the same issue

Comment: @ArmandoBarreda: Since you are not using `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, the camera should return a `Bitmap` to you via `data.getParcelableExtra("data")`. There is no `Uri`.